# Laravel is and is not empty value check

Tags: php, laravel

I know we can check whether value is empty or not like:

```
@if(!empty(test))
//print results
@endif
```

but what if we want to cross check 2 columns for being empty and not being empty?

Sample:

I want check between: `$test->one` and `$test->two`

1. If `$test->one` is **not empty** and `$test->two` **is empty** = x
2. If `$test->one` and `$test->two` **both are not empty** = y

How do I do that?

## UPDATE

My code:

PS:

1. `$test->one` in my sample is equal to `$order->options_price`
2. `$test->two` in my sample is equal to `$order->shipment_price`

   @if(!empty($order->product_data))

   ```
     {{ number_format($order->total_price(), 0) }}

   @elseif(!empty($order->options_price) && empty($order->shipment_price))

     {{ number_format($order->quantity * $order->price + $order->options_price, 0) }}

   @elseif(!empty($order->options_price) && !empty($order->shipment_price))

     {{ number_format($order->quantity * $order->price + $order->options_price + $order->shipment, 0) }}

   @else

     {{ number_format($order->quantity * $order->price, 0) }}

   @endif
   ```

The problem is i cannot get `shipment_price`

FIXED:

I did have typing mistake in my code.

Comment: use if else and use logical operator `&&`

Comment: Am I missing something? `@if(!empty($test->one) && empty($test->two)` etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do

> If $test->one is not empty and $test->two is empty

```
@if(!empty($test->one) && empty($test->two))
//print results
@endif
```

> If $test->one and $test->two both are not empty

```
@if(!empty($test->one) && !empty($test->two))
//print results
@endif
```

Comment: please change `empty` with `!empty` in your second code .

Answer (score 0):

Laravel also provides the [`blank`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/helpers#method-blank) helper method.

Examples from the docs:

```
blank('');
blank('   ');
blank(null);
blank(collect());

// true

blank(0);
blank(true);
blank(false);

// false
```